# how to get out of for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am very new to python programming and started a day ago. I am not getting out of for loop.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)

    print("Hello")
```

I want to print hello once after coming out of the for loop.

Comment: Just add the print("hello") statement after for loop ends i.e. next line

Comment: indentation matters in python.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i) # This is inside for loop

#LOOP ENDS    
print("Hello") # This is out of for-loop
```

The for-loop ends after `print(i)` because the next statement, `print("Hello")` is not indented.